# Can I upgrade my kernel with a kernel for an other distribution?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I have a raspberry on Raspbian and a vm on Kali linux.
My question is simple : 
Kali is based on Debian. 
Kali last kernel is 4.19 but Debian last kernel is about 4.9. 
So, can I add debian sources.list to my Kali and upgrade my kernel to Debian 4.9 ?

I tried and it seems to work.

Is the upgrade of kernel possible only with distributions that have the same packet manager (yum, apt...) ?

Thanks !

Proc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, since as you noted both are based on the Debian distro. Sticking with the same distro and package manager is the safest route. While many distros offer interoperability options (e.g. [Alien](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alien-pkg-convert/)) the conventional wisdom is summed up rather well here:

> Because different distribution families use different packaging systems (Debian: *.deb / CentOS: *.rpm / openSUSE: *.rpm built specially for openSUSE), a package intended for one distribution will not be compatible with another distribution. However, most distributions are likely to fall into one of the three distribution families covered by the LFCS certification.

From https://www.tecmint.com/linux-package-management/

Also, a handy super-reference for distros and packaging: [Distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=package-management)